# Cannot acces the websphere console from web browser

Tags: console, websphere, virtualhost, websphere-8

I have an error with accessing the websphere server console, which is weird is that i am able to acces it from the RAD as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

But when I try to access the console from the web browser I get the following error:

[image]

which means A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle / has not been defined
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle localhost:9444has not been defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console is not on 9444 port but probably in your setup on 9043 or 9044. Your RAD correctly uses this port, but in web browser your are typing incorrect one.

Comment: And how is this possible, when i check the server properties i see that the https port is 9444 !!!!!

Comment: There are 2 pairs of ports : 9081/9444 for default trafic, and 9061/9044 for administration trafic. Your application will be on 9444, but admin console is on 9044. This is traffic separation for security/management reasons